# WHITESPACE in Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have problem with my website i have whitespace background between img and text on the right side on the screen, take a look of my screenshots to see what i mean,i will provide the code to see if i actualy make mistake in my code to programming this website i use bootstrap to be responsive on mobile but however you see in my screenshots is not. how can i fix this can anyone have solution? i try whit bootstrap use d-block but its still showing me whitespace.

[image]

[image]

HTML

```css
.myimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60em;
  left: 60em;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.myimg2 {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 35%;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37em;
  left: 23em;
  color: azure;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

.mytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48em;
  color: wheat;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutMe">
  <img src="Images/background.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="bg">
  <div class="aboutMeContent ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="myimg">
          <img src="Images/me.jpg" alt="me" class="myimg2">
        </div>
        <h1 class="name">Stefan Momcilovic</h1>
        <h4 class="col-sm-6 text-center mytext"><i>Hello dear visitors I am Stefan Momcilovic, I'm a web development from high school, so far I have several projects that I've made some of you can see in my portfolio, programming has been interesting since my early years, but for the first time I entered in programming is on elementary school I made games that you can find on a google play store, and from high school I'm doing web development, I hope we will work together on your project in the future,Have nice day!</i></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is because you have space between <div class="myimg"> and <img src="Images/... ( lines return are spaces )

Comment: Also why is the background image not a background ?

Comment: I know that is probably "wierd" but it doesn't work when my bg set to css i know why but im layz to fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the CSS `left` propery to `0` so that there is no gap between the left side of the HTMLElement and page.

```css
.myimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60em;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.myimg2 {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 35%;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37em;
  left: 0;
 
  color: azure;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

.mytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48em;
  left: 0;
  color: wheat;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutMe">
  <img src="Images/background.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="bg">
  <div class="aboutMeContent ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="myimg">
          <img src="Images/me.jpg" alt="me" class="myimg2">
        </div>
        <h1 class="name">Stefan Momcilovic</h1>
        <h4 class="col-sm-6 text-center mytext"><i>Hello dear visitors I am Stefan Momcilovic, I'm a web development from high school, so far I have several projects that I've made some of you can see in my portfolio, programming has been interesting since my early years, but for the first time I entered in programming is on elementary school I made games that you can find on a google play store, and from high school I'm doing web development, I hope we will work together on your project in the future,Have nice day!</i></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1- if you want to make the responsive page and improve your code, an absolute position not suitable for the responsive page.

2- when you use absolute position, consider the relative position for the parent node as well as consider the box model of the parent;

for your question, if you remove left or assign left:0  then overflow-x eliminated.

for example :

```
.myimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```